# How can I offset a scaffold widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-layout, offset

I want to design a custom navigation window like the one below.

[image]

I planned to:

1. Create my navigation widget
2. Create my news feed widget
3. Stack both widgets (news feed on top of the navigation)
4. If the menu icon is clicked, translate the news feed widget to some value so that the underneath nav widget is visible

I did the first three steps. I have problems with the fourth one. I set an *Offset* state variable and placed my scaffold widget within a *Positioned* widget. I set the 'left' of the *Positioned* class to *Offset.dx*.

Code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';

    void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: new ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: const MaterialColor(0xfff06000, const {
                   50: const Color(0xfffff0e6),
                  100: const Color(0xffffd1b3),
                  200: const Color(0xffffb380),
                  300: const Color(0xffff944d),
                  400: const Color(0xffff751a),
                  500: const Color(0xfff06000),
                  600: const Color(0xffcc5200),
                  700: const Color(0xffb34700),
                  800: const Color(0xff993d00),
                  900: const Color(0xff662900),
                })),
            //I stack the classes
            home: new Stack(
              children: [
                new MyNavPage(),
                new MyHomePage(title: "Home",initialOffset: new Offset(0.0, 0.0),),
              ],
            )
        );
      }
    }

    // This is my news feed class

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

      final String title;
      final Offset initialOffset;

      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.initialOffset}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State with TickerProviderStateMixin {

      Offset position = new Offset(0.0, 0.0);

      int _counter = 0;

      void _incrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
          _counter++;
        });
      }

      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        position = widget.initialOffset;
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        final scaffold = new Scaffold(
          primary: true,
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text(widget.title),
            centerTitle: true,
            leading: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.menu),onPressed: () => setState(() => position = new Offset(100.0, 0.0)),),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
          body: new Container(
            child: new Center(
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  new Text(
                    'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    '$_counter',
                    style: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .display1,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        );

        return new Positioned(
          left: position.dx,
          child:scaffold,
        );
      }

    }

    // My navigation class. It has those navigation options as a column to the left.
    // The width is 100.0, hence I offset my home page by 100.0


    class MyNavPage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyNavPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _MyNavPageState createState() => new _MyNavPageState();
    }

    class _MyNavPageState extends State {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Expanded createNavChild(Icon i, Text t) {
          return new Expanded(
            child: new GestureDetector(
              child: new Container(
                width: 100.0,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red,),
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    i,
                    t
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }

        return new Scaffold(
          primary: true,
          body: new Container(
            margin: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .padding,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                createNavChild(new Icon(Icons.home, size: 30.0), new Text("Home")),
                createNavChild(
                    new Icon(Icons.person_add, size: 30.0), new Text("Register")),
                createNavChild(
                    new Icon(Icons.search, size: 30.0), new Text("Player Search")),
                createNavChild(
                    new Icon(Icons.event, size: 30.0), new Text("Events")),
                createNavChild(new Icon(Icons.file_download, size: 30.0),
                    new Text("Downloads")),
                createNavChild(
                    new Icon(Icons.call, size: 30.0), new Text("Contact")),
              ],
            ),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent,),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

An error is thrown:

```
I/flutter ( 3090): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 3090): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 3090): RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter ( 3090): This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
I/flutter ( 3090): inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
I/flutter ( 3090): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is:
I/flutter ( 3090):   RenderStack#df1fd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):   creator: Stack ← Semantics ← Builder ← RepaintBoundary-[GlobalKey#274fe] ← IgnorePointer ←
I/flutter ( 3090):   FadeTransition ← FractionalTranslation ← SlideTransition ← _MountainViewPageTransition ←
I/flutter ( 3090):   AnimatedBuilder ← RepaintBoundary ← _FocusScopeMarker ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 3090):   parentData:  (can use size)
I/flutter ( 3090):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, h=640.0)
I/flutter ( 3090):   size: Size(360.0, 640.0)
I/flutter ( 3090):   alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart
I/flutter ( 3090):   textDirection: ltr
I/flutter ( 3090):   fit: loose
I/flutter ( 3090):   overflow: clip
I/flutter ( 3090): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is:
I/flutter ( 3090):   RenderStack#df1fd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):   creator: Stack ← Semantics ← Builder ← RepaintBoundary-[GlobalKey#274fe] ← IgnorePointer ←
I/flutter ( 3090):   FadeTransition ← FractionalTranslation ← SlideTransition ← _MountainViewPageTransition ←
I/flutter ( 3090):   AnimatedBuilder ← RepaintBoundary ← _FocusScopeMarker ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 3090):   parentData:  (can use size)
I/flutter ( 3090):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, h=640.0)
I/flutter ( 3090):   size: Size(360.0, 640.0)
I/flutter ( 3090):   alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart
I/flutter ( 3090):   textDirection: ltr
I/flutter ( 3090):   fit: loose
I/flutter ( 3090):   overflow: clip
I/flutter ( 3090): The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were:
I/flutter ( 3090):   BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
I/flutter ( 3090): The exact size it was given was:
I/flutter ( 3090):   Size(Infinity, Infinity)
I/flutter ( 3090): See https://flutter.io/layout/ for more information.
I/flutter ( 3090): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 3090): #0      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints. (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1698:9)
I/flutter ( 3090): #1      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1772:6)
I/flutter ( 3090): #2      RenderBox.size=. (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1507:17)
I/flutter ( 3090): #3      RenderBox.size= (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1507:65)
I/flutter ( 3090): #4      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:354:5)
I/flutter ( 3090): #5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #6      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #8      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #9      _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1141:11)
I/flutter ( 3090): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #11     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:553:15)
I/flutter ( 3090): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #13     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #15     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #19     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #21     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #23     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #25     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #27     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #28     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2712:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #30     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:514:15)
I/flutter ( 3090): #31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #32     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #34     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #36     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #38     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #40     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:107:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1570:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #42     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:125:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #43     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1445:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #44     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:709:18)
I/flutter ( 3090): #45     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:270:19)
I/flutter ( 3090): #46     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:627:13)
I/flutter ( 3090): #47     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:208:5)
I/flutter ( 3090): #48     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter ( 3090): #49     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter ( 3090): #50     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame. (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:751:7)
I/flutter ( 3090): #52     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter ( 3090): #53     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter ( 3090): #54     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)
I/flutter ( 3090): (elided one frame from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 3090): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter ( 3090):   RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#04aef relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):   creator: CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
I/flutter ( 3090):   _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#64807 ink renderer] ← NotificationListener ←
I/flutter ( 3090):   PhysicalModel ← AnimatedPhysicalModel ← Material ← PrimaryScrollController ← _ScaffoldScope ←
I/flutter ( 3090):   Scaffold ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 3090):   parentData:  (can use size)
I/flutter ( 3090):   constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
I/flutter ( 3090):   size: Size(Infinity, Infinity)
I/flutter ( 3090): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter ( 3090):   RenderPositionedBox#4ac32 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):     RenderFlex#a08f4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):       RenderParagraph#eba89 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):       RenderParagraph#5afd6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):   RenderConstrainedBox#0b71f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):     RenderPhysicalModel#fa853 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):       _RenderInkFeatures#45d75 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):         RenderPositionedBox#7bd87 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):           RenderPadding#3faff NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):   RenderStack#4eccb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):     RenderTransform#16934 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):       RenderTransform#317f7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):         RenderSemanticsAnnotations#f02cf NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090):           RenderConstrainedBox#75c14 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3090): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Questions:

1. Is my approach correct?
2. If it is correct, what is the error telling me?
3. If it is not the right approach, is there a simpler or better way to achieve this?

Comment: Why is there a `new MyNavPage()` at the start of the `build` method? Have you tried using/extending a standard app drawer with `Scaffold` and changing the width?

Comment: @JacobPhillips My bad. That line shouldn't be there. Edited it. As to your second question, I don't want the drawer to slide on top of my home widget. I want the home widget itself to slide and reveal the drawer beneath it. That is why I didn't use the inbuilt drawer.

Answer (score 5):

Let me know if I'm wrong about this, but it sounds like you want the navigation drawer to open when the user clicks the menu button. Thankfully, Flutter already handles this!

You can simply use the Scaffold's `drawer` property. You pass it a drawer (or possibly another widget) to show, and it will automatically handle making it available for swiping in from the left.

If you also want to open it on a button press, you can use `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();` from your button. Note that to get the context that includes the scaffold, you'll have to use a [Builder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) or make your appbar a new widget.

Comment: Yes. Flutter has a drawer property. But drawer is stacked on top of my home widget and the drawer itself slides. But I want my home widget to slide right and thereby reveal the underneath drawer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah sorry missed the underneath part!

Answer (score 0):

Packages Hidden Drawer Menu

[image]

These packages are very simple to use. Link to the packages is [here](https://pub.dev/packages/hidden_drawer_menu).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post, but it looks like none of the responses so far fully answer your question.

The reason for your error is that the default `Positioned` constructor doesn't specify its child's position with respect to any edge not passed to it. You only specify the position with respect to the left edge, leaving the position with respect to the other edges unconstrained. You need to use `Positioned.fill` to make sure that your page fills the screen.

In `_MyHomePageState`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  [...]
  
  return new Positioned.fill(
    left: position.dx,
    child:scaffold,
  );
}
```

However, it seems like the effect you want is for your main page to slide to the right when you open the navigation menu. To achieve this, you can use a horizontally-scrolling `SingleChildScrollView` containing your main page and navigation menu instead of a `Stack`:

#### MyApp

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _showNavigationRail() {
    final isClosed = _controller.offset == 0;
    final target = isClosed ? _controller.position.maxScrollExtent : 0.0;
    _controller.animateTo(
      target,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        // Start with the scroll view scrolled all the way to the right, which
        // corresponds to the navigation rail being hidden.
        reverse: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _controller,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            NavigationRail(
              selectedIndex: 0,
              labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
              destinations: const [
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: Text('Home'),
                ),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person_add),
                  label: Text('Register'),
                ),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  label: Text('Search'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox.fromSize(
              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
              child: HomePage(showNavigationDrawer: _showNavigationRail),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### HomePage

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback showNavigationDrawer;

  const HomePage({super.key, required this.showNavigationDrawer});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() => setState(() => _counter++);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: widget.showNavigationDrawer,
        ),
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
            Text('$_counter', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Here's](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e447590182efa28cfc0691f28b17f00d) a complete example that you can try on DartPad.

#### Result

[image: Screen recording]

Note that this answer uses Dart 3, and it looks like your code uses a version of Dart that predates null safety.